# Pyspark - Looking to create a normalized version of a Double column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As the title states, I'd like to create a normalized version of an existing Double column.

As I'm quite new to pyspark, this was my attempt at solving this:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('id').count().toDF(*['id','count_trans'])
df2 = df2.withColumn('count_trans_norm', F.col('count_trans) / (F.max(F.col('count_trans'))))
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
"grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`movie_id`' is not an aggregate function.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an empty window if you want to get the maximum of `count_trans` in `df2`:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('id').count().toDF(*['id','count_trans'])
df3 = df2.selectExpr('*', 'count_trans / max(count_trans) over () as count_trans_norm')
```

Or if you prefer pyspark syntax:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df3 = df2.withColumn('count_trans_norm', F.col('count_trans') / F.max(F.col('count_trans')).over(Window.orderBy()))
```